# Using apache tomcat with wamp server

Tags: apache, tomcat, wamp

How do i use apache tomcat with the wamp server. I have a couple of applets that need to be run on my server but it appears that wamp does not support applets. I need to install tomcat into my wamp server. How do i do this.

Answer (score 4):

What can be done between apache and tomcat is using a bridge named [apache tomcat connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/index.html)